# why does this $2\sin^{2}\frac{1}{2n}\leq2(\frac{1}{2n})^2$ hold?

Tags: calculus

Saw this in an explanation, but could not understand why this holds. Can someone explain why this holds?

Comment: for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we have $\sin x \leq x$. Of course, it's also true for $x > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ is a positive integer, then this just follows from the fact that

$$ \sin x \le x $$

for every nonnegative $x$, with equality when $x = 0$.

Note that $\sin \frac{1}{2n} > 0$ for every $n \in \mathbf{Z}^+$ then apply the above result.

Comment: ah, it was that easy, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you work out the Taylor series of $\sin x$ about $0$ you will obtain

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O(x^7)\leq x,|x|<1.$$

Then just substitute $x=\frac{1}{2n}$, square, and multiply by $2$.